# An elementary fact about tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an $R$-right module, $N$ be a submodule of $R$-left module $M$, $\pi:M\rightarrow M/N
 $ is the natural epimorphism. What is $\ker\left(\pi\otimes1_{A}\right)
 $?

I  appreciate your help.

Comment: See the long exact sequence at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_functor

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Ah, OK, thanks! I still think the notation $A$ for a module is unexpected, when your other modules are $M$ and $N$.

Comment: There was no ambiguity in the question, really. One's expectations always lose to explicitly introduced notation!

Answer (score 2):

We have the short exact sequence 
$$ 0 \to N \xrightarrow[]{i} M \xrightarrow[]{\pi}  M/N \to 0$$

Tensor on the right by $A$ and get a right exact sequence

$$N \otimes A \xrightarrow[]{i\otimes 1_A} M \otimes A \xrightarrow[]{\pi\otimes 1_A}  (M/N)\otimes A \to 0$$

Therefore, the kernel is the submodule of $M\otimes A$ generated by $i(n)\otimes a$ with $n\in N$ and $a \in A$.

Note that $i \otimes 1_A$ may not be injective.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}$
Let $N\subseteq M$ and $A$ be as in the question. In general, there is not a simple description of the kernel of the map $M\otimes A\to M/N\otimes A$.

Given modules $X$ and $Y$ (on the right and on the left, respectively) there is a standard way to construct an abelian group $\Tor(X,Y)$; this can be done in several ways, one of which is very similar to the construction of the tensor product itself and which you can find explained in MacLane's book *Homology*. Along with the construction of this abelian group one shows that whenever we have a short exact sequence $$0\to X'\to X\xrightarrow{f} X''\to 0$$ of right modules, we get an exact sequence $$\Tor(X'',Y)\xrightarrow{\partial} X'\otimes Y\to X\otimes Y\xrightarrow{f\otimes1_Y} X''\otimes Y\to 0$$ for a certain map $\partial$. In this way we get a description of the kernel of $f\otimes1_Y$ as the quotient $(X'\otimes Y)/\partial(\Tor(X'',Y))$.

In your specific case, what we get from the short exact sequence $0\to N\to M\xrightarrow{f} M/N\to 0$ is the exact sequence $$\Tor(M/N,A)\to N\otimes A\to M\otimes A\xrightarrow{f\otimes1_A} M/N\otimes A\to 0$$ and the isomorphism $\ker(f\otimes1_A)\cong (N\otimes A)/\partial(\Tor(M/N,A))$.

One can find examples showing that pretty much anything can happen, so this description is as good as it gets.

For example, if $M/N$ is free or flat, or if $A$ is flat, then $\Tor(M/N,A)$ is zero and the kernel is just $X'\otimes Y$. It may happen also that the $Tor$ is nonzero and the map $\partial$ is zero. It may happen that the map $\partial$ is an isomorphism, and then your kernel is zero. It may well happen that neither $M/N$ nor $A$ are flat, yet $\Tor(M/N,A)$ is nevertheless zero. Etc.

In general, the kernel depends on the actual structures of the modules $M$, $N$, and $A$, and on the way $N$ sits inside $M$ (so that one can pick a different submodule $N'$ in $M$ which is isomorphic to $N$ but for which the kernel in question is different).

Comment: Finding examples of all that is something that everyone learning about Tor should do at some point!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are wondering about the map 
$ M \otimes A \rightarrow M/N \otimes A$. 
$A$ is free and so flat as $A$-module which means $\ker \pi \otimes A$ is a submodule of $M \otimes A$. It is clearly in the kernel of $\pi \otimes 1$.
Now think of a an element of $\pi \otimes 1$. You can see it's of the form $u \otimes 1$ for $u \in M$. Then again by flatness, argue that $u \in \ker \pi$.

Comment: Why are you assuming that A is free? Notice the ring is $R$ here...

Comment: A is not necessarily free

Answer (score 1):

> Let $K\stackrel f\to M\stackrel g\to L\to 0$ and $K'\stackrel {f'}\to M'\stackrel {g'}\to L'\to 0$ be two short exact sequences. Then $$\ker (g\otimes g')=\operatorname{im}(f\otimes1_{M'})+\operatorname{im}(1_M\otimes f').$$

In your case $\ker(\pi\otimes 1_A)=\operatorname{im}(\iota\otimes1_{A})$, where $\iota:N\to M$ is the inclusion. One can also write $$\ker(\pi\otimes 1_A)=\langle \{x\otimes a:x\in N, a\in A\}\rangle.$$ 
(One can prove directly the last claim: denote the right hand side by $D$, and show that there is a well-defined map $q:M/N\otimes A\to (M\otimes A)/D$ such that $q(\pi(x)\otimes a)=x\otimes a\bmod D$, so $\ker(\pi\otimes 1_A)\subseteq D$. The converse is obvious.)